# xcode instruments keeps opening old project instead of current

Tags: xcode, project, instruments

I'm running a build of a project on ios and it works fine. When I go to instruments and profile the project it opens up some old project.  I've tried restarting both xcode and instruments and it is still opening some old project. Usually it always profiles the latest current project on the iphone that I've just run.

What do I need to reset?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the app on the iphone fixed the problem.